# Office 365 Outlook Addin - mailbox.item.body.appendOnSendAsync Not Working on Mac OS

Tags: outlook, office-js, outlook-addin, office-addins, outlook-web-addins

I have an Outlook addin that utilizes the **appendOnSendAsync** function.

```
 Office.context.mailbox.item.body.appendOnSendAsync(
       "<img src='xxxx' />",
        {
          coercionType: Office.CoercionType.Html
        },
        function(asyncResult) {
          console.log(asyncResult);
        }
      );
```

I do a check for the below before enabling it.

```
Office.context.requirements.isSetSupported('MailBox', '1.9')
```

The feature works as designed when testing it on **outlook.com**. However, on my Mac OS Outlook (version 16.66.2), the function does not seem to append the pixel like it does when I send a message on **outlook.com**.

Is there anything else I need to be doing to get it to work on my Outlook Mac client?

Below is how I initiate the call. I don't reference the below in the Manifest since its not triggered by any buttons within the toolbar. Again, this code works on Outlook.com but not on my Mac Outlook with the new UI.

```
jQuery("#track_email_code").on("click", function(){
  var pixel_code = jQuery("#track_email_code").val();
  if(Query("#track_email_code").is(":checked")) {             
      appendText = '<img src="XXXXXXX'+pixel_code+'" />';  
  }
  else {
      appendText = '';
  }
  
  Office.context.mailbox.item.body.appendOnSendAsync(
    appendText,
    {
      coercionType: Office.CoercionType.Html
    },
    function(asyncResult) {
      console.log(asyncResult);
    }
  );
  
});
```

Here is my manifest file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<OfficeApp
  xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/appforoffice/1.1"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xmlns:bt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/officeappbasictypes/1.0"
  xmlns:mailappor="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/mailappversionoverrides"
  xsi:type="MailApp">
      <Id>xxxxxxxxxxx</Id>

      <!--Version. Updates from the store only get triggered if there is a version change. -->
      <Version>2.0.1.6</Version>
      <ProviderName>xxxxxx</ProviderName>
      <DefaultLocale>en-US</DefaultLocale>
      <!-- The display name of your add-in. Used on the store and various places of the Office UI such as the add-ins dialog. -->
      <DisplayName DefaultValue="xxxxxx" />
      <Description DefaultValue="xxxx"/>

      <!-- Icon for your add-in. Used on installation screens and the add-ins dialog. -->
      <IconUrl DefaultValue="https://xxxxx/icon_64.png" />
      <HighResolutionIconUrl DefaultValue="https://xxxxx/icon.png"/>

      <!--If you plan to submit this add-in to the Office Store, uncomment the SupportUrl element below-->
      <SupportUrl DefaultValue="https://xxxxx.com" />

      <!-- Domains that will be allowed when navigating. For example, if you use ShowTaskpane and then have an href link, navigation will only be allowed if the domain is on this list. -->
      <AppDomains>
        <AppDomain>https://xxxxxx.com</AppDomain>
        <AppDomain>https://o365.xxxxxx.com</AppDomain>
      </AppDomains>
      <!--End Basic Settings. -->

      <Hosts>
        <Host Name="Mailbox" />
      </Hosts>
      <Requirements>
        <Sets>
          <Set Name="Mailbox" MinVersion="1.1" />
        </Sets>
      </Requirements>
      <FormSettings>
        <Form xsi:type="ItemRead">
          <DesktopSettings>
            <SourceLocation DefaultValue="https://xxxxxx/beta/index.html"/>
            <RequestedHeight>250</RequestedHeight>
          </DesktopSettings>
        </Form>
      </FormSettings>

      <Permissions>ReadWriteMailbox</Permissions>
      <Rule xsi:type="RuleCollection" Mode="Or">
        <Rule xsi:type="ItemIs" ItemType="Message" FormType="Read" />
      </Rule>
      <DisableEntityHighlighting>false</DisableEntityHighlighting>

         
      <VersionOverrides xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/mailappversionoverrides" xsi:type="VersionOverridesV1_0">
        <Requirements>
          <bt:Sets DefaultMinVersion="1.1">
            <bt:Set Name="Mailbox" />
          </bt:Sets>
        </Requirements>
        <Hosts>
          <Host xsi:type="MailHost">            
            <DesktopFormFactor>
              <!-- Location of the Functions that UI-less buttons can trigger (ExecuteFunction Actions). -->
              <FunctionFile resid="functionFile" />
                        <ExtensionPoint xsi:type="MessageReadCommandSurface">
                          <OfficeTab id="TabDefault">
                            <Group id="msgReadMMGroup">  
                              <Label resid="groupLabel"/>
                              <Control xsi:type="Button" id="msgComposeAddContact">
                                <Label resid="addContactLabel"/>
                                <Supertip>
                                  <Title resid="addContactTitle"/>
                                  <Description resid="addContactDesc"/>
                                </Supertip>
                                <Icon>
                                  <bt:Image size="16" resid="icon16"/>
                                  <bt:Image size="32" resid="icon32"/>
                                  <bt:Image size="80" resid="icon80"/>
                                </Icon>
                                <Action xsi:type="ShowTaskpane">
                                  <SourceLocation resid="readEmailContactPaneUrl" />
                                </Action>
                                    
                              </Control>                        
                            </Group>
                          </OfficeTab>
                        </ExtensionPoint>
                        <ExtensionPoint xsi:type="MessageComposeCommandSurface">
                          <OfficeTab id="TabDefault">
                            <Group id="msgComposeCmdGroup">                      
                              <Label resid="groupLabel"/>
                              <Control xsi:type="Button" id="msgComposeInsertGist">
                                <Label resid="insertGistLabel"/>
                                <Supertip>
                                  <Title resid="insertIconTitle"/>
                                  <Description resid="insertGistDesc"/>
                                </Supertip>
                                <Icon>
                                  <bt:Image size="16" resid="icon16"/>
                                  <bt:Image size="32" resid="icon32"/>
                                  <bt:Image size="80" resid="icon80"/>
                                </Icon>
                                <Action xsi:type="ShowTaskpane">
                                  <SourceLocation resid="addActivityUrl" />
                                </Action>
                              </Control>                        
                            </Group>
                          </OfficeTab>
                        </ExtensionPoint>

                        <ExtensionPoint xsi:type="AppointmentAttendeeCommandSurface">
                              <OfficeTab id="TabDefault">
                                <Group id="apptAttendeeGroup">
                                  <Label resid="groupLabel"/>
                                  <Control xsi:type="Button" id="apptAttendeeOpenPaneButton">
                                    <Label resid="logActivityLabel"/>
                                    <Supertip>
                                      <Title resid="logActivityLabel"/>
                                      <Description resid="logActivityDesc"/>
                                    </Supertip>
                                    <Icon>
                                       <bt:Image size="16" resid="icon16"/>
                                       <bt:Image size="32" resid="icon32"/>
                                       <bt:Image size="80" resid="icon80"/>
                                    </Icon>
                                    <Action xsi:type="ShowTaskpane">
                                      <SourceLocation resid="meetingContactPaneUrl"/>
                                    </Action>
                                  </Control>
                         
                                </Group>
                              </OfficeTab>
                            </ExtensionPoint>
                            <ExtensionPoint xsi:type="AppointmentOrganizerCommandSurface">
                              <OfficeTab id="TabDefault">
                                <Group id="msgReadGroup">
                                  <Label resid="groupLabel"/>
                                  <Control xsi:type="Button" id="msgReadOpenPaneButton">
                                    <Label resid="logActivityLabel"/>
                                    <Supertip>
                                      <Title resid="logActivityLabel"/>
                                      <Description resid="logActivityDesc"/>
                                    </Supertip>
                                    <Icon>
                                       <bt:Image size="16" resid="icon16"/>
                                       <bt:Image size="32" resid="icon32"/>
                                       <bt:Image size="80" resid="icon80"/>
                                    </Icon>
                                    <Action xsi:type="ShowTaskpane">
                                      <SourceLocation resid="meetingContactPaneUrl"/>
                                    </Action>
                                  </Control>
                         
                                </Group>
                              </OfficeTab>
                            </ExtensionPoint>
              <!-- Go to http://aka.ms/ExtensionPointsCommands to learn how to add more Extension Points: MessageRead, AppointmentOrganizer, AppointmentAttendee -->
            </DesktopFormFactor>
          </Host>
        </Hosts>        
        <Resources>
          <bt:Images>
            <bt:Image id="icon16" DefaultValue="https://xxxxxx/assets/mm_icon_16.png"/>
            <bt:Image id="icon32" DefaultValue="https://xxxxxx/assets/mm_icon_32.png"/>
            <bt:Image id="icon80" DefaultValue="https://xxxxxx/assets/mm_icon_80.png"/>
          </bt:Images>
          <bt:Urls>
            <bt:Url id="functionFile" DefaultValue="https://xxxxxx/beta/function-file/function-file.html"/>
            <bt:Url id="messageReadTaskPaneUrl" DefaultValue="https://xxxxxx/beta/index.html"/>
             <bt:Url id="addActivityUrl" DefaultValue="https://xxxxxx/beta/msg-compose/activity.html"/> 
             <bt:Url id="readEmailContactPaneUrl" DefaultValue="https://xxxxxx/beta/contacts/index_mobile.html"/>   
             <bt:Url id="apptContactPaneUrl" DefaultValue="https://xxxxxx/beta/contacts/index_mobile.html"/>    
             <bt:Url id="meetingContactPaneUrl" DefaultValue="https://xxxxxx/beta/contacts/index_mobile.html"/>
          </bt:Urls>
          <bt:ShortStrings>
            <bt:String id="logMeetingLabel" DefaultValue="Log Meeting"></bt:String>
            <bt:String id="logActivityLabel" DefaultValue="xxxxxxxxxxx Log Activity"></bt:String>
            <bt:String id="groupLabel" DefaultValue="xxxxxxxxxxx"/>
            <bt:String id="customTabLabel"  DefaultValue="My Add-in Tab"/>
            <bt:String id="paneReadButtonLabel" DefaultValue="Display all properties"/>
            <bt:String id="paneReadSuperTipTitle" DefaultValue="Get all properties"/>                   
            <bt:String id="addContactTitle" DefaultValue="Add Contacts to xxxxxxxxxxx"></bt:String>
            <bt:String id="addContactLabel" DefaultValue="xxxxxxxxxxx"></bt:String>
            <bt:String id="insertGistLabel" DefaultValue="Log Email"></bt:String>
            <bt:String id="insertGistTitle" DefaultValue="Log Email"></bt:String>
            <bt:String id="insertIconTitle" DefaultValue="Log Email"></bt:String>
            <bt:String id="insertDefaultGistLabel" DefaultValue="Insert Default Gist"><bt:Override Locale="es-ES" Value="Inserte el Gist predeterminado"/></bt:String>
            <bt:String id="insertDefaultGistTitle" DefaultValue="Insert Default Gist"><bt:Override Locale="es-ES" Value="Inserte el Gist predeterminado"/></bt:String>
                 
          </bt:ShortStrings>
          <bt:LongStrings>
            <bt:String id="logActivityDesc" DefaultValue="Log activity to xxxxxxxxxxx"></bt:String>
            <bt:String id="addContactDesc" DefaultValue="Add/Update Contacts"></bt:String>                  
            <bt:String id="paneReadSuperTipDescription" DefaultValue="Opens a pane displaying available properties. This is an example of a button that opens a task pane."/>
                    <bt:String id="insertGistDesc" DefaultValue="Allows you to log emails to your xxxxxxxxxxx Account.">
                       <bt:Override Locale="es-ES" Value="Muestra una lista de sus Gists y permite insertar su contenido en el mensaje actual"/>
                     </bt:String>
                     <bt:String id="insertDefaultGistDesc" DefaultValue="Inserts the contents of the Gist you mark as default into the current message">
                       <bt:Override Locale="es-ES" Value="Inserta el contenido de lo Gist que marca como predeterminado en el mensaje actual"/>
                     </bt:String>
          </bt:LongStrings>
        </Resources>
      
      <VersionOverrides xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/mailappversionoverrides/1.1" xsi:type="VersionOverridesV1_1">
        <Requirements>
          <bt:Sets DefaultMinVersion="1.1">
            <bt:Set Name="Mailbox" />
          </bt:Sets>
        </Requirements>
        <Hosts>
          <Host xsi:type="MailHost">
            <DesktopFormFactor>
              <!-- Location of the Functions that UI-less buttons can trigger (ExecuteFunction Actions). -->
              <FunctionFile resid="functionFile" />
                        <ExtensionPoint xsi:type="MessageReadCommandSurface">
                          <OfficeTab id="TabDefault">
                            <Group id="msgReadMMGroup">  
                              <Label resid="groupLabel"/>
                              <Control xsi:type="Button" id="msgComposeAddContact">
                                <Label resid="addContactLabel"/>
                                <Supertip>
                                  <Title resid="addContactTitle"/>
                                  <Description resid="addContactDesc"/>
                                </Supertip>
                                <Icon>
                                  <bt:Image size="16" resid="icon16"/>
                                  <bt:Image size="32" resid="icon32"/>
                                  <bt:Image size="80" resid="icon80"/>
                                </Icon>
                                <Action xsi:type="ShowTaskpane">
                                  <SourceLocation resid="readEmailContactPaneUrl" />

                                <SupportsPinning>true</SupportsPinning>
                                </Action>
                                
                              </Control>                        
                            </Group>
                          </OfficeTab>
                        </ExtensionPoint>
                        <ExtensionPoint xsi:type="MessageComposeCommandSurface">
                          <OfficeTab id="TabDefault">
                            <Group id="msgComposeCmdGroup">                      
                              <Label resid="groupLabel"/>
                              <Control xsi:type="Button" id="msgComposeInsertGist">
                                <Label resid="insertGistLabel"/>
                                <Supertip>
                                  <Title resid="insertIconTitle"/>
                                  <Description resid="insertGistDesc"/>
                                </Supertip>
                                <Icon>
                                  <bt:Image size="16" resid="icon16"/>
                                  <bt:Image size="32" resid="icon32"/>
                                  <bt:Image size="80" resid="icon80"/>
                                </Icon>
                                <Action xsi:type="ShowTaskpane">
                                  <SourceLocation resid="addActivityUrl" />
                                  <SupportsPinning>true</SupportsPinning>
                                </Action>
                              </Control>                        
                            </Group>
                          </OfficeTab>
                        </ExtensionPoint>

                        <ExtensionPoint xsi:type="AppointmentAttendeeCommandSurface">
                              <OfficeTab id="TabDefault">
                                <Group id="apptAttendeeGroup">
                                  <Label resid="groupLabel"/>
                                  <Control xsi:type="Button" id="apptAttendeeOpenPaneButton">
                                    <Label resid="logActivityLabel"/>
                                    <Supertip>
                                      <Title resid="logActivityLabel"/>
                                      <Description resid="logActivityDesc"/>
                                    </Supertip>
                                    <Icon>
                                       <bt:Image size="16" resid="icon16"/>
                                       <bt:Image size="32" resid="icon32"/>
                                       <bt:Image size="80" resid="icon80"/>
                                    </Icon>
                                    <Action xsi:type="ShowTaskpane">
                                      <SourceLocation resid="meetingContactPaneUrl"/>
                                    </Action>
                                  </Control>
                     
                                </Group>
                              </OfficeTab>
                            </ExtensionPoint>
                            <ExtensionPoint xsi:type="AppointmentOrganizerCommandSurface">
                              <OfficeTab id="TabDefault">
                                <Group id="msgReadGroup">
                                  <Label resid="groupLabel"/>
                                  <Control xsi:type="Button" id="msgReadOpenPaneButton">
                                    <Label resid="logActivityLabel"/>
                                    <Supertip>
                                      <Title resid="logActivityLabel"/>
                                      <Description resid="logActivityDesc"/>
                                    </Supertip>
                                    <Icon>
                           <bt:Image size="16" resid="icon16"/>
                           <bt:Image size="32" resid="icon32"/>
                           <bt:Image size="80" resid="icon80"/>
                                    </Icon>
                                    <Action xsi:type="ShowTaskpane">
                                      <SourceLocation resid="meetingContactPaneUrl"/>
                                    </Action>
                                  </Control>
                     
                                </Group>
                              </OfficeTab>
                            </ExtensionPoint>
              <!-- Go to http://aka.ms/ExtensionPointsCommands to learn how to add more Extension Points: MessageRead, AppointmentOrganizer, AppointmentAttendee -->
            </DesktopFormFactor>
            <MobileFormFactor>
              <FunctionFile resid="residUILessFunctionFileUrl" />
              <ExtensionPoint xsi:type="MobileMessageReadCommandSurface">
                <Group id="mobileMsgRead">
                  <Label resid="groupLabel" />
                  <Control xsi:type="MobileButton" id="mobileMessageRead">
                    <Label resid="addContactLabel"/>
                    <Icon xsi:type="bt:MobileIconList">
                       <bt:Image size="25" scale="1" resid="icon32" />
                        <bt:Image size="25" scale="2" resid="icon32" />
                        <bt:Image size="25" scale="3" resid="icon32" />
                        <bt:Image size="32" scale="1" resid="icon32" />
                        <bt:Image size="32" scale="2" resid="icon32" />
                        <bt:Image size="32" scale="3" resid="icon32" />
                        <bt:Image size="48" scale="1" resid="icon80" />
                        <bt:Image size="48" scale="2" resid="icon80" />
                        <bt:Image size="48" scale="3" resid="icon80" />
                    </Icon>
                    <Action xsi:type="ShowTaskpane">
                      <SourceLocation resid="readEmailMobileContactPaneUrl" />
                    </Action>
                  </Control>
                </Group>
              </ExtensionPoint>
            </MobileFormFactor>
          </Host>
        </Hosts>
        <Resources>
          <bt:Images>
            <bt:Image id="icon16" DefaultValue="https://xxxxxx/assets/mm_icon_16.png"/>
            <bt:Image id="icon32" DefaultValue="https://xxxxxx/assets/mm_icon_32.png"/>
            <bt:Image id="icon80" DefaultValue="https://xxxxxx/assets/mm_icon_80.png"/>
          </bt:Images>
          <bt:Urls>
            <bt:Url id="functionFile" DefaultValue="https://xxxxxx/beta/function-file/function-file.html"/>
            <bt:Url id="messageReadTaskPaneUrl" DefaultValue="https://xxxxxx/beta/index.html"/>
                 <bt:Url id="addActivityUrl" DefaultValue="https://xxxxxx/beta/msg-compose/activity.html"/>
                 <bt:Url id="readEmailContactPaneUrl" DefaultValue="https://xxxxxx/beta/contacts/index_mobile.html"/>
                 <bt:Url id="readEmailMobileContactPaneUrl" DefaultValue="https://xxxxxx/beta/contacts/index_mobile.html"/>
                 <bt:Url id="meetingContactPaneUrl" DefaultValue="https://xxxxxx/beta/contacts/index_mobile.html"/>
          </bt:Urls>
          <bt:ShortStrings>
            <bt:String id="logMeetingLabel" DefaultValue="Log Meeting"></bt:String>
            <bt:String id="logActivityLabel" DefaultValue="xxxxxxxxxxx Log Activity"></bt:String>
            <bt:String id="addContactTitle" DefaultValue="Add Contacts to xxxxxxxxxxx"></bt:String>
            <bt:String id="addContactLabel" DefaultValue="xxxxxxxxxxx"></bt:String>
            <bt:String id="groupLabel" DefaultValue="xxxxxxxxxxx"/>
            <bt:String id="customTabLabel"  DefaultValue="My Add-in Tab"/>
            <bt:String id="paneReadButtonLabel" DefaultValue="Display all properties"/>
            <bt:String id="paneReadSuperTipTitle" DefaultValue="Get all properties"/>
            <bt:String id="insertGistLabel" DefaultValue="Log Email"></bt:String>
            <bt:String id="insertGistTitle" DefaultValue="Log Email"></bt:String>
            <bt:String id="insertIconTitle" DefaultValue="Log Email"></bt:String>        
          </bt:ShortStrings>
          <bt:LongStrings>              
            <bt:String id="logActivityDesc" DefaultValue="Log activity to xxxxxxxxxxx"></bt:String> 
            <bt:String id="addContactDesc" DefaultValue="Add/Update Contacts"></bt:String>
            <bt:String id="paneReadSuperTipDescription" DefaultValue="Log Email"/>
            <bt:String id="insertGistDesc" DefaultValue="Allows you to log emails to your xxxxxxxxxxx Account." />
            <bt:String id="insertDefaultGistDesc" DefaultValue="Log Email" />
          </bt:LongStrings>
        </Resources>
        <ExtendedPermissions>
          <ExtendedPermission>AppendOnSend</ExtendedPermission>
        </ExtendedPermissions>
       </VersionOverrides>  
      </VersionOverrides>

    </OfficeApp>
```

Comment: We tried the API at our end and it works fine on mentioned build. How are you launching the addin ? Is it an event based addin ? Is it possible for you to share the manifest file of your addin?

Comment: It is not an event based action. I believe I would not need to add it to the manifest if I and simply calling the function in a callback function. I added the code above in the post.

Comment: You must include the AppendOnSend permission in your manifest irrespective of how this API being used. Please check the Answer section for more details.

Comment: Yes, I do have that in there. If that wasn't in there then on outlook.com, the appendOnSendAsync would not work right?

Comment: Can you share your addin's manifest so, that we can try to repro this at our end and check if  anything is missing ?

Comment: Yes see above in post.

Comment: Could you give us the exact image URL which you are using in your addin? Best way would be to copy the value of img src. 

And are you running your addin in nested compose or full compose?

Comment: We tried the following code snippet on Mac and it appended the image when we sent the email. Could you try this code snippet?

 `Office.context.mailbox.item.body.appendOnSendAsync(
       "<img src='https://pngimg.com/uploads/strawberry/small/strawberry_PNG2586.png'/>",
        {
          coercionType: Office.CoercionType.Html
        },
        function(asyncResult) {
          console.log(asyncResult);
            console.log("Done");
        }
      );`

Comment: This helps a little but still having trouble. When I click send, I see the strawberry image being added quickly, but then it disappears after a split second. I checked the sent folder and viewed the source of the sent messages and no longer see the strawberry image in there. What would make it disappear on my Mac but not on outlook.com, is it some setting perhaps?

Comment: Is the image attached in the received email? Can you try sending an email to yourself and send a video of the issue with the email in inbox as well as sent items? Also can you give us the original URL which was not working? We think there might be some problem with the URL syntax. As for the image, it should be attached in both sent and received email after sending.

Comment: Is there an email or a way to private message you with this info?

Comment: here is a redacted version https://tempclip.com/en/OD9iLWzs6aN1eer/watch

Comment: Emailed the test add-in and video as requested. Looking forward to hear back. thanks

Comment: Thanks @james for reporting this issue regarding AppendOnSend API. We have been able to reproduce this with the addin provided by you and it has been put on our backlog. We unfortunately have no timelines to share at this point . The internal tracking id is 719918.

Answer (score 0):

The classic UI on Mac OS doesn't support the Mailbox requirement set 1.9. See [Outlook JavaScript API requirement sets](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/requirement-sets/outlook/outlook-api-requirement-sets?view=excel-js-preview&tabs=xmlmanifest) for more information.

Make sure that you did everything like described on the [Implement append-on-send in your Outlook add-in](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/outlook/append-on-send?tabs=xmlmanifest) page. For example, the last point from the guide suggests registering the event handler in the following way:

```
Office.actions.associate("appendDisclaimerOnSend", appendDisclaimerOnSend);
```

Comment: I'm using the new UI on Mac OS.  My addin is slightly different where I am not triggered it via a button click as in the example. But yes, I don't think I need to register the function b/c I'm not trigger it from a click.  The addin works on the Outlook web version just not on the new UI on my Mac OS.

Comment: I'd suggest posting it as an issue to the `OfficeJS` repo at GitHub then, see https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-js/issues .

Answer (score 0):

To enable the append-on-send feature in your add-in, you must include the AppendOnSend permission in the collection of ExtendedPermissions as mentioned [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/outlook/append-on-send?tabs=xmlmanifest#:%7E:text=To%20enable%20the%20append%2Don%2Dsend%20feature%20in%20your%20add%2Din%2C%20you%20must%20include%20the%20AppendOnSend%20permission%20in%20the%20collection%20of%20ExtendedPermissions) in documentation.
Your manifest should have following entry :

```
<ExtendedPermissions>
  <ExtendedPermission>AppendOnSend</ExtendedPermission>
</ExtendedPermissions>
```